# how to change hwnd attributes

Tags: c++, winapi

```
const HWND window = CreateWindowExW(
    WS_EX_TOPMOST |WS_EX_TRANSPARENT |WS_EX_LAYERED,
    wc.lpszClassName,
    L"Sexy window frfr",
    WS_POPUP,
    0, 0,
    GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN),
    nullptr,
    nullptr, 
    wc.hInstance,
    nullptr);
```

I'm trying to set the WS_EX_TRANSPARENT to off when I click VK_INSERT but I can't find any function that does that.

Comment: Take a look at [SetWindowLong](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowlonga) with the `GWL_EXSTYLE` flag.

Comment: Better to use `SetWindowLongPtr()` in modern code, to support both 32bit and 64bit builds.